# Multi-permission Firestore security rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My website has multiple accounts with different permissions.

I use custom claims inside the Firestore token to give the right access to the user.

So far it has worked perfect with this setup:

The claims for User 1 with access to 1 location looks like this: `{"companyLocation": "testLocation1"}`

Soon I will have users who can access one or more locations. For example User 2 can access "testLocation2" & "testLocation3" without having access to "testLocation1".

User 2 claims can for example have a seperator (" ¤ ") and look something like this: `{"companyLocation": "testLocation2 ¤ testLocation3"}`

How would I achieve this with security rules? I tried:

```
function checkMultipleLocations(){
  return request.auth.token.companyLocation.contains('testLocation2');
}
```

This gives me an error stating:

> Invalid function name: contains

In the docs it states you can use `in: v in x` (Checks if value v is in list x), but this does not work for lists (does not return true), works only for objects/maps (tried by splitting the user claim string into array, without luck).

Any ideas?

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/f6qvpm/multipermission_firestore_security_rules/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in` operator works on a list only. The value of this claim `{"companyLocation": "testLocation2 ¤ testLocation3"}` is not a list, but a string. So the `in` operator won't work here.

---

For a list of supported operators, see the documentation for the [string type in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String). This doesn't mention a `contains` method, but **does** have a `matches` method, which allows you to accomplish this use case.

```
request.auth.token.companyLocation.matches('.*testLocation2.*')
```

---

You could also try to store the claim as an array:

```
{"companyLocation": ["testLocation2", "testLocation3"]}
```

If setting a claim like this works, the `in` operator *should* work. I'm saying *should* here, because recently somebody was having trouble setting claims like this, and I haven't tested it myself.